# Dealing with non-significant results in the Wilcoxon signed rank test

Tags: statistical-significance, wilcoxon-signed-rank, friedman-test

A little background:

I'm trying to create a weighted formula for artists telling me how good they are based on the ratings I assign them for different characteristics they have. Basically I'm going to survey some people, asking them to rank order the characteristics in order of importance. From here I want the check that there is a significant difference between characteristics ranks and the average rank (basically confirming that the characteristics should be weighted differently). I was planning on using the Friedman test for this.

From here, I want to pairwise compare each of the different characteristics to each other to check they are significantly different using the Wilcoxon signed rank test. My problem is what do I do when it comes back saying they aren't significantly different. In order to assign different weightings to the characteristics, I want them to be significantly different.

I have run a small test survey with 13 participants, and when I run the Wilcoxon test to compare the different characteristics about 50% come back not being significantly different. I'm not sure if this is a consequence of my small sample size, but any general advice on how to deal with not significant results in terms of ranked data would be much appreciated.